# JSON-LD JobPosting with multiple locations: "Missing '}' or object member name."

Tags: json, json-ld

I'm trying to put together a `JobPosting` that has multiple locations listed. In the Structured Data Type Definitions listed on the developers.google.com site, it says:

> If the job has multiple locations, add multiple jobLocation properties in an array. Google will choose the best location to display based on the job seeker's query.

But I continue to get an error:

```json
  "jobLocation":[
{
    "@type":"Place",
    "address":{
        "@type":"PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress":"1366 N Mockingbird Ln.",
        "addressLocality":"Abilene",
        "addressRegion":"TX",
        "postalCode": "79603",
    }    
}
{
    "@type":"Place",
    "address":{
        "@type":"PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress":"3301 South 1st Street",
        "addressLocality":"Abilene",
        "addressRegion":"TX",
        "postalCode": "79603"
    }
}
]
```

> Missing '}' or object member name.

The item that is highlighted is the first closing bracket after the first `postalCode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the comma in `"postalCode": "79603",`, and add a comma to separate the items in the array:

```json
"jobLocation": [
  {},
  {}
]
```

Comment: thanks for the help, that seems to have fixed that. but now it is giving me an error on each Property. if i remove a property, it just gives the error on the next one underneath it. and it's always the same error.

Missing ',' or '}' in object declaration.

    "datePosted": "2018-04-19",

Comment: @PhillipLong: You would need to show the code in a new question, if you can’t find the error yourself. The rules should be quite simple: no comma after the last property in an object, everything else gets one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a comma after the ] - here is how it worked for me:

```
        "jobLocation": [
        {
            "@type": "Place",
            "address": {
                "@type": "PostalAddress",
                "streetAddress": "XYZ",
                "addressLocality": "XYZ",
                "postalCode": "XYZ",
                "addressCountry": "DE"
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "Place",
            "address": {
                "@type": "PostalAddress",
                "streetAddress": " XYZ",
                "addressLocality": "XYZ",
                "postalCode": "XYZ",
                "addressCountry": "DE"
            }
        }

    ],
```